# How does webpack's require.ensure work?

Tags: javascript, webpack

From the [docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html), you can do this:

```
require.ensure(["module-a", "module-b"], function(require) {
    var a = require("module-a");
    // ...
});
```

`require.ensure` does not evaluate the modules until you `require()` them. Later, they give another example,

```
require.ensure([], function(require) {
  let contacts = require('./contacts')
});
```

Where the ensure array is empty.

So my questions are:

1. Do I have to specify my modules twice? Once as the first argument to `require.ensure` and again inside the callback? Are there differences between specifying or omitting that first arg?
2. The callback gives me back a new `require` function but we already have a global one. Is there a difference between the local one and global one? <del>Can webpack even differentiate them, since it has to do this statically?</del>

Comment: *"Can webpack even differentiate them, since it has to do this statically?"* It can certainly know that the inner one refers to the parameter of the callback.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it'll work even if you pass an empty array.

Comment: @flyingSmurfs But is there a difference? Does webpack just fill in the empty array with all the inner requires or what?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: @FelixKling Okay, so that answers (1). What about (2)?

Comment: I am interested in the answers to this question as well.

Comment: @FelixKling So...apparently Webpack *can't* really differentiate them statically. You have to name the param `require`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack now [supports](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-) `import()`, which is more convenient to use. `require.ensure` still supported, so back to your questions:

1. You don't have to specify modules twice. Webpack statically parses the source code and adds all modules mentioned in the first argument array **and** all `require`d within callback function body modules to a distinct chunk
2. Actually the function passed to `callback` is not used and you should always use global `require`. This is quirky behavior that I have noted at the official webpack [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require-ensure).

Comment: `import()` isn't strictly the same though. That'll evaluate the script as soon as it finishes downloading, no? Whereas `require.ensure` will make sure the scripts are downloaded before firing the callback, but not evaluate them until you explicitly require them. I'm not entirely sure when you'd need this distinction, but it's there :-) Anyway, thank you for answering my question! I had a feeling there was something quirky going on with that `require` param.

Comment: yes, that's true - `import()`ed module is evaluated immediately, in opposite to `require.ensure` 